# Константы как имена полей базы данных?

Tags: php, laravel

Вопрос по константам.

Дано Ларавел. Решено было использовать константы, хранимые в Eloquent, которые используются для именования колонок таблицы. Т.е. и в целом в проекте, и в миграциях. Чтобы была единая точка входа.

1) Верное ли это решение?

2) Вроде как если используем константы, то нужно их использовать везде, даже во view. Но не будет ли это странно? Например берем раздельно бекенд, и фронтенд. Откуда верстальщик будет знать константы колонок, он просто задампит, что ему приходит, и будет видеть названия колонок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обо всём по порядку.

#### 1 Верное ли это решение?

Да. Верно.

#### 2 Вроде как если используем константы, то нужно их использовать везде, даже во view. Но не будет ли это странно? Например берем раздельно бекенд, и фронтенд. Откуда верстальщик будет знать константы колонок, он просто задампит, что ему приходит, и будет видеть названия колонок.

Не совсем так. Во `view` должна передаваться модель. И фронтенд разработчик должен работать с объектом модели.

Comment: Спасибо! Если говорить об архитектуре приложений в целом, то что тогда делать с константами (или их отсутствием), в архитектуре типа Symfony, где используются анемичные модели/сущности?
У них же для названий колонок используются методы и свойства, которые не получится задать константами.

Comment: И еще момент, если это верный ход, как тогда получит доступ к этим свойствам, если они прописаны константой?

$article = new Article();
$article->(Article::TITLE)='text'; не работает

Comment: Константы позволяют избавляться от копипаста и, в случае изменения в приложении, уменьшить трудозатраты на переделку. Всё-таки значение 1 константы изменить проще, чем 100500 литералов или имён переменных в разных файлах.

Comment: Что касаемо Symphony-based фреймворков, то это скорее частный случай и здесь нужно смотреть специфику конкретного решения.

Comment: `$article->(Article::TITLE)='text'; не работает`-это и не должно работать. Есть специальный синтаксис `$value = $obj['proprtyName'];`. Вместо `propertyName` можно задействовать текстовую константу. (см. в [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/sdo.sample.getset.php))